# nginx server_name based on $hostname

Tags: nginx, hostname

Based on the [Nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24hostname) the `$hostname` variable is *set to the machine's hostname as returned by gethostname*.

I tried that and although `gethostname` doesn't work my Debian box it still returns the host correctly.
Then I tried to use that variable `$hostname` to set the `server_name`, but that didn't work.

Why is that and is there another way I can accomplish that?

```
server {
    listen   80;

    autoindex off;

    server_name  static.$hostname;
    root   /var/www/static;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
        index  index.html;
    }

    error_page  404  /404.html;
    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most variables in nginx only exist at runtime, not during configuration time.

For this reason, most variables cannot be used with the `server_name` directive.  Since `$hostname` is a constant value, there's an explicit check for *exactly* `$hostname` in the `server_name` handler.

It only allows for the `server_name` to be set to `$hostname`, not `static.$hostname`.  You may be able to patch the source to make it support that feature (`ngx_http_core_module.c`, look for `$hostname`), but you can't do it with the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You should find this works:

```
server_name static.*;
```

Comment: This would be incredibly insecure and allow host header injection attacks to anyone who sets "static.malicioushostnamehere.com" as an example.

Comment: I have worked with use cases where this is fine, but other use cases this is incredibly insecure. Know the risks.