# Use variable for server_name in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use a variable in nginx in `server_name`, but is not working. Is this possible?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    set $foo "bar.example.com";
    server_name $foo;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it's not possible unless you want to set it to exactly the $hostname variable.

Ref:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
- [nginx server_name based on $hostname](https://serverfault.com/questions/338504/nginx-server-name-based-on-hostname)